# Access thread local variable in JVMTI Agent

Tags: java, jvm, jvmti

I have got the hold of a `jthread` in particular event in JVMTI agent. How do I get:

- access to thread local variable
- the thread name and id

from within the JVMTI agent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jthread` is a regular JNI reference to `java.lang.Thread` object. You can use it to access fields and invoke methods on Thread instance, e.g.

```
    jclass threadClass = jniEnv->FindClass("java/lang/Thread");
    jmethodID methodID = jniEnv->GetMethodID(threadClass, "getId", "()J");
    jlong id = jniEnv->CallLongMethod(thread, methodID);
```

Alternatively you may use JVMTI [`GetThreadInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetThreadInfo) function to get thread name as `char*`.

Thread locals of a thread can be accesses through package-private [`threadLocals`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5b7b2c1d3d21/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l180) field.

Comment: [sorry for long pause], I tried getting threadId (with same code) from Java's Object's constructor (from native method) and I ran into [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/16069205/), class `java/lang/Thread` has been loaded already ofcourse

Comment: @JigarJoshi ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I can hardly tell what you've made wrong without any details.

Comment: sorry about that, [This is the code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/16071541/) which gets followed through during constructor of Object, after once VM has started, all User object will follow through here, agent is attached, all is good if I remove method call, I am happy to provide more detail, please let me know, Thanks!

Comment: @JigarJoshi `Thread.toString` apparently creates new objects => infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing local variables you may call GetLocalVariabletable() to retrieve a table (array) of variable entries and using slot number for a variable obtained from variable entry you may call getlocalXXX series of functions to obtain the value of the variable depending on the variables signature (also obtained from variable table entry )and set it using setlocalXXX() functions.To further read object subclasses i.e class objects you may use jni series of functions upon the jobject retrieved using getlocalobject.